Laravel Stripe webhooks, how to know the authenticated user so that the job can update user account on successful purchase?
In my Laravel 8 app I'm using Stripe-provided payment links from my Stripe account to provide a purchase widget in my app's pricing blade and process payment through Stripe's checkout page. This all works fine, and I can use Spatie's laravel-stripe-webhooks to catch the webhooks generated and process the payload in the job.
The issue I'm having is that I need to update the user account with his/her Stripe customer ID and other info from their purchase, and the payload doesn't know/indicate who my user is, so that I can update the correct user account. I can't feed this to the job, as it can't see any session variables I set on the front end (when the user clicks the payment widget), as they don't persist across the checkout process and on return to my app. The Stripe-provided payment link doesn't allow for the passing of data, such as a user ID, in metadata, like I could do in code if I programmatically started a checkout intent session in my controller. Since my user is authenticated when they make the purchase I thought I could simply read Auth::user() in the job, but that doesn't work either (not quite sure why).
This must be a fairly common issue, processing and updating a user in a webhook job, so I'm hoping someone has a solution I can't see that gets me from here to there.

I have not directly worked with laravel, but you can include a client_reference_id using Payment Links: https://docs.stripe.com/payment-links/url-parameters#streamline-reconciliation-with-a-url-parameter. You can attach a unique string of your choice to the Checkout Session like a customer ID. If you add this parameter to your payment link, it’s sent in the checkout.session.completed webhook event.

Yes, but I can't use that parameter with the button/widget link. It seems it's just a reference to a configuration back at Stripe as no matter what changes I make in the dashboard the buy-button-id doesn't change. I can add a metadata parameter, like client_reference_id at the dashboard, but that doesn't allow me to change that data to my customer DI back in my code. Here's the button code:
<stripe-buy-button
            buy-button-id="buy_btn_1Pxxx...qq0"
            publishable-key="pk_test_51Oxxx...Rob"
            >
 </stripe-buy-button>

"Since my user is authenticated when they make the purchase I thought I could simply read Auth::user() in the job, but that doesn't work either (not quite sure why)." - because a webhook means their systems are making a request to your server. The client browser is not even involved in that part; therefor you do not get any cookie with a session ID either.

Exactly, hence my dilemma. Looks like I'll be resorting to a Stripe link and build my own widget around it, so that I can pass parameters through the process, and abandon the Stripe-provided button panel.
